# Find $f(x)$ concave and $g(y)$ convex such that $f(x)/g(y)$ is convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm looking for two functions $f(x)$ concave and $g(y)$ convex such that their ratio $h(x,y)=f(x)/g(y)$ is convex. Both $f$ and $g$ cannot be constant. Their domain of definition can be $R$ or any subset of $R$. Ideally, their image would include at least part of $R_+$. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The function $g$ can not have positive values. If for a fixed $y_*$ you have $g(y_*)>0$, then the function $x\to f(x)/g(y_*)$ is concave, which contradicts the convexity of the function $(x,y)\to f(x)/g(y)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would it help if we were interested in having the square of the ratio $h(x,y)=(f(x)/g(y))^2$ convex instead?

Comment: Can't really say right now, but it will definitely change a lot of things. After all, there are concave functions that, after squaring, become convex.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Actually, it's fine if $f(x)=x$. In that case even if $g$ has positive value the ratio could be convex.